# task max thread value in wildfly 10.1

Tags: performance, load, wildfly, wildfly-10

i want to support 7k requests per minute for my system . Considering there are network calls and database calls which might take around 4-5 seconds to complete . how should i configure task max threads and max connections to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

This is just math.

7k requests/minute is roughly 120 requests/second.

If each request is taking 5s then you will have roughly 5 x 120 = 600 inflight requests.

That's 600 HTTP connections, 600 threads and possibly 600 database connections.

These numbers are a little simplistic but I think you get the picture.

Note the standard Linux stack size for each thread is 8MB, therefore 600 threads is going to want nearly 5GB of memory just for the stacks. This is configurable at the OS level - but how do you size it?

Therefore you're going to be up for some serious OS tuning if you're planning to run this on a single server instance.